# JSON nest class data binding

Tags: java, json, jackson

`{ "type":"cat",  "animal":{"name":"cat"} }`

Animal is an `abstract class`. Cat and Dog are `subclass`.

Now I am trying to `convert json to java object` and want to use "type" to get the subclass.

But the type field is out of animal the column.

Thanks in advance :)

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property= "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),
    @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") })
abstract class Animal {
    public String name;
}



class Cat extends Animal {
public String name;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
public String name;
}
```

the question is the type is out of animal{}.

if the type is in the animal{} the code will works. but it isn`t ):

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, but type in JSON should looks like `"type":"com.test.Cat"` (fully qualified name)
Abstract class

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
public abstract class AAnimal 
{
}
```

subclasses

```
public class Cat extends AAnimal
{
   public String name;
} 
public class Dog extends AAnimal
{
   public String name;
}
```

now, for json

```
"{ \"type\":\"com.test.Dog\", \"name\":\"gav-gav\" }"
```

it will be `Dog` instance
and for

```
"{ \"type\":\"com.test.Cat\", \"name\":\"mew-mew\" }"
```

it will be `Cat` instance
**EDIT**
In this case use `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY`. Example

```
public class Container 
{
   private String type;

   private AAnimal animal;

   public String getType()
   {
      return type;
   }

   public void setType(String type)
   {
      this.type = type;
   }

   public AAnimal getAnimal()
   {
      return animal;
   }

   @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property="type")
   public void setAnimal(AAnimal animal)
   {
      this.animal = animal;
   }
}
```

Animal classes

```
public abstract class AAnimal 
{
   public String name;
}
public class Cat extends AAnimal
{
}
public class Dog extends AAnimal
{
}
```

for

```
"{\"type\":\"com.test.Cat\", \"animal\" : {\"name\":\"cat\" }}"
```

it works well.
**PS.**
Also you can use `use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS`, in this case you can use only part of fully qualified name
**EDIT2**

```
   @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property="type")
   @JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"), @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") })
   public void setAnimal(AAnimal animal)
   {
      this.animal = animal;
   }
```

works well for

```
"{\"type\":\"cat\", \"animal\" : {\"name\":\"cat\" }}"
```

Comment: but the type field is not in the animal {}

Comment: If the type must be 1 or 2, How can I change the JsonTypeInfo? The type value is given by others and I can not change it to com.package.Cat ):  @llya

Comment: hi @llya I met a problem again. When I deserialization, I got two type columns:{"type": 1,"type": "1",}

Comment: @Felix I don't know answer yet. I may be able to answer in 3 hours. Please, create new question for it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048738/serialization-and-deserialization-with-jackson-exception  because of getting two type field my deserialization failed ):