# Serialization and Deserialization with Jackson Exception

Tags: java, json, jackson

[JSON nest class data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038084/json-nest-class-data-binding)
as the answer did, When I Serialization and Deserialization the Container I got this exception:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not find a Value deserializer for abstract type [simple type, class com.xiaonei.wap.ps.model.Container]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._handleUnknownValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:321)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:116)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:260)
at
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove or rename setter/getter for `type` field

```
public class Container 
{
   private AAnimal animal;

   public AAnimal getAnimal()
   {
      return animal;
   }

   @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property="type")
   @JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"), @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") })
   public void setAnimal(AAnimal animal)
   {
      this.animal = animal;
   }
}    

public abstract class AAnimal 
{
   public String name;
}
```

test

```
  String json = "{\"type\":\"cat\", \"animal\" : {\"name\":\"cat-mew\" }}";
  Container val = o.readValue(json, Container.class);
  System.out.println(o.writeValueAsString(val));
```

output is

```
{"animal":{"name":"cat-mew"},"type":"cat"}
```

Comment: if I remove the type field, I got this:org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "type" (Class com.chat.jsonobject.Message), not marked as ignorable

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer of the link you've provided, you need to explicitly mention the `type` of the objects as external property, as the type doesn't belong to the parent class. This `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` adds the type property to the upper heirarchy.

Therefore, this `type` as an external property should be existent in the converted piece. So, when you are removing that `type` from json, it get's no explicit default implementation for that property. That is why you need to add a default implementation class in the `defaultImpl` parameter in the annotation.

So, to fix the issue, you can add the `AAnimal.class` as the `defaultImpl`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
        property = "type",
        defaultImpl = AAnimal.class
)
@JsonSubTypes({ 
    @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"), 
    @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") 
})
public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
}
```

Now if you omit the `type` from the input json, and test with:

```
String json = "{\"animal\" : {\"name\":\"cat-mew\" }}";
```

You'll get:

```
{"animal":{"name":"cat-mew"},"type":"AAnimal"}
```