# Java: Jackson polymorphic JSON deserialization of an object with an interface property?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, polymorphism

I am using Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to deserialize a JSON representation of an object that contains an interface as one of its properties. A simplified version of the code can be seen here:

https://gist.github.com/sscovil/8735923

Basically, I have a class `Asset` with two properties: `type` and `properties`. The JSON model looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "document",
    "properties": {
        "source": "foo",
        "proxy": "bar"
    }
}
```

The `properties` property is defined as an interface called `AssetProperties`, and I have several classes that implement it (e.g. `DocumentAssetProperties`, `ImageAssetProperties`). The idea is that image files have different properties (height, width) than document files, etc.

I've worked off of the examples in [this article](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html), read through docs and questions here on SO and beyond, and experimented with different configurations in the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation parameters, but haven't been able to crack this nut. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Most recently, the exception I'm getting is this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Could not deserialize JSON.
...
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve type id 'source' into a subtype of [simple type, class AssetProperties]
```

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION:**

With many thanks to @Michał Ziober, I was able to resolve this issue. I was also able to use an Enum as a type id, which took a bit of Googling. Here is an updated Gist with working code:

https://gist.github.com/sscovil/8788339

Comment: What does the Json output look for something like this? Is there a bunch of embedded metadata?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the programmerbruce post. What a great resource

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` instead of `JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY`. In this scenario your `Asset` class should look like this:

```
class Asset {

    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
            property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImageAssetProperties.class, name = "image"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DocumentAssetProperties.class, name = "document") })
    private AssetProperties properties;

    public AssetProperties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(AssetProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Asset [properties("+properties.getClass().getSimpleName()+")=" + properties + "]";
    }
}
```

See also my answer in this question: [Jackson JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757431/jackson-jsontypeinfo-as-external-property-doesnt-work-as-expected/20914599).

Comment: Add the annotations to the property, not the class...of course! Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: Now do it for a list of interfaces, please. ... :)

Comment: How yours `POJO`s and `JSON` look like?