# how to deal with interfaces at jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, abstract

I am dealing with this problem. I have this class:

```
public class SemaphoreResponse {
    ISemaphore semaphore;
    StatusHolder statusHolder;

    public SemaphoreResponse() {
        super();
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

I want to convert my json string to that class, and it throws me this exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.despegar.henry.automation.services.semaphoreservice.response.ISemaphore, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@17a5f5a5; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.despegar.henry.automation.services.semaphoreservice.response.SemaphoreResponse["semaphore"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.instantiationException(StdDeserializationContext.java:233)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:60)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
```

So, i understand that this is happening because the "semaphore" attribute, which is an interface, so into that interface i know i have to add @JsonDeseralize like this

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = [class-name].class)
public interface ISemaphore {
    public abstract String getId();

    public abstract void setId(String id);

    public abstract String getOwnerUserId();

}
```

But this is my problem. The attribute semaphore from SemaphoreResponse doesn't use always same class. ergo, i have two different classes called "MainSemaphore" and "ExecutionSemaphore", which both implements the interface ISemaphore. So, at the time for deserealization i want to pass the class that i want the interface adapts for as a parameter.

It would be something like

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = MainSemaphore.class) or @JsonDeserialize(as = ExecutionSemaphore.class) depending the case
```

How could i do that? I would appreciate your help

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. See [this article](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) referenced from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485923/java-jackson-polymorphic-json-deserialization-of-an-object-with-an-interface-pr)

Comment: @llawj references the correct way to handle the polymorphism but I suspect you're not going to get the results you expect serializing a Semaphore...

Comment: Do you know how to set the property path? I can't found this any where. Because i am mapping the StatusHolder property (which is an abstract class right now) and to make polymorphism it depends from the "type" attribute, located into Semaphore. Do you know how to to that? I don't know if i am clear otherwise let me know. Regards

Comment: With more than one implementation, you do need to use `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation on interface; and JSON must have type id include in some way (either as an additional property, or using wrapper Object or Array, where type id is either key (for Object) or first element (for Array).. So ProgrammerBruce's article helps here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides full polymorphic handling, described by excellent article by ProgrammerBruce, there is also a simpler way to just support simple interface/impl, one-to-one, case: register mapping via module:

`SimpleModule m = new SimpleModule(...);
    m.addAbstractTypeMapping(ISemaphore.class, SemaphoreImpl.class);
    mapper.registerModule(m);`

and this would instruct Jackson to always deserialize things declare as `ISemaphore` using concrete class `SemaphoreImpl`.

Comment: Thanks! i have already solved it! but i have one more problem now. I described it us a comment up. Regards