# Deserialize a JSON class that has interface properties without using annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I want to deserialize a JSON representation of an object that contains an interface as one of its properties. The class of the object looks something Like this:

```
class A {
    B b;
}

Interface B {
   //some content
}
Class C implements B {
}
Class D implements B {

}
```

I thought jackson is the best to do this.

The simplest way is to put some annotations above interface B as mentioned in the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485923/java-jackson-polymorphic-json-deserialization-of-an-object-with-an-interface-pr) . But the problem here is I do not have access to change any of those classes or interface. So I cannot put annotations in class A. Is there another way to achieve the same?

Comment: You'll have to use a [custom deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, I thought about writing a class exactly same as A and deserialize the json to that object. But then I will have to set each member of class A object manually

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Add a deserializer to the `ObjectMapper` and add in your custom logic there.

Comment: You can use http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations if you don't want to change your classes or interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Fast dirty workaround:

You can deserialize the class C first and set as a class A's attribute

Formal method:

This is a kind of deserialization strategy which you may want to determine whether it's a class C or class D by the content of JSON, which is custom deserialization