# Deserializing abstract types in jersey using jackson

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson

I am writing a rest api and at the compile time i only have the model interfaces which i want to use as dto in my rest api. I dont want my rest api to have dependency of model implementations at compile time as i have diggerent jars for dealing with different databases. So it is obvious that jersey is not able to deserialize the json as it is not aware of the concrete type. I googled about instantiating abstract types but all the solutions are for compile time only wbich is not an option for me. Any help would be much appriciated.

```
@POST
public Response addMessage(Message message) {
    // How to deserialize message since Message is an interface
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you ever seen this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21513939/1426227)?