# jackson polymorphic deserialization without field

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I am able to try out simple cases of polymorphic deserialization in jackson.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
@Type(value = A.class, name = "a"),
@Type(value = B.class, name = "b")
})
Class Base {
  private String type;
...
}

Class A extends Base {
...
}

Class B extends Base {
...
}
```

But I am facing is where the I dont have control on the incoming Json. The json looks like

`{ "type" : a, "params" : {  .. fields for type A ..   } }`

`{ "type" : b, "params" : {  .. fields for type B ..   } }`

The `params` field can be of either A or B type. Both `A` and `B` inherit from `Base` but the column which decides the `type` is outside the `params` field.

How do I configure jackson to look at a field outside the class and then decide the actual type

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from 
[Java: Jackson polymorphic JSON deserialization of an object with an interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485923/java-jackson-polymorphic-json-deserialization-of-an-object-with-an-interface-pr)

We need to put the annotations on the variable being deserialized with an external property

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = A.class, name = "a"),
    @Type(value = B.class, name = "b") 
})
```