# Spring MVC bind on a typed field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object grid(Search<MyFilter> search){
      ...
    }
```

My Search object is like:

```
public class Search<F extends Filter> {
    private int offset;
    private int size;
    private F filter;

    //... getters/ setters
}
```

Filter is just an Interface. `MyFilter` is an implementation of `Filter` with some fields like `name,` `title`, etc.

I'm doing an HTTP GET to this controller with: `/search?offset=0&size=10&filter.name=john`

But spring can't instantiate MyFilter. I've tried to make `Filter` a normal empty class and `MyFilter` to extend it, but it's not possible either.

Is it possible to spring to instantiate the correct filter and then bind the values?

Comment: Write a custom resolver or create one method per type.

Comment: @zeroflagL can you explain that? Post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** No, Spring won't instantiate `MyFilter` from parametrized type.

The `Search` object is instantiated, when request arrives.
The problem is, that at runtime information about type parametrization is erased and converted to the most general type. I mean that at runtime your `Search` object effectively will look like:

```
class Search {

    /*
     * F is replaced by Filter since it is the most general type 
     * for <F extends Filter> parametrization. 
     * This will be the only Search class representation that compiler generates.
     */
    private Filter filter;

    //Rest of class body omitted
}
```

This is how generics works. Sicne `Filter` is an interface the object mapper has no clue how it should be resolved. You could guide object mapper how to resolve `Filter` into specific class based on i.e. additional type parameter (I belive that such case is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21513939/5684265)). But I don't think if mixing this with generics is good idea. It will lead to complex and confusing code.

You obviously depend on `MyFilter` implementation so you could use the approach from @DeezCashews suggestion. Or you could think of more flexible solutions. If all kinds of Filter are just containers of fields names and of wanted values you could do something like:

```
public class Search {
    private int offset;
    private int size;
    private List<FieldPredicateTuple> filters;

    //getters and setters omitted
}

public class FieldPredicateTuple {
    String field;
    String value;

    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

And then call endpoint: `/search?offset=0&size=10&filters[0].field=name&filters[0].value=john`

I don't know how you want use those filters so I don't know what to propose. But I'd recommend to redesign this somehow.

Comment: The FieldPredicateTuple solutions is too complex... Not a good one. But, your answer NO is what i needed.

Comment: Type is actually not completely erased, it still can find out the type implementation from either the method argument's generic info or a field's generic info. ActFramework has just implemented the feature. see https://github.com/actframework/actframework/issues/413

Comment: @GelinLuo  You've said _"it still can find out the type implementation from either the method argument's generic info or a field's generic info"_ - Could you point me the relevant code for that? I think the type implementation is found out from the parameter incoming via http, not from method argument's info. Let's assume the method from the question takes `Search<Integer> search`. In spite of it it's perfectly legal to call endpoint `/search?filter=john`. The method runs (with `String` "john" as the value of filter field) and eventually throw runtime error when you try to use it as `Integer`.

Comment: @JakubCh. I am not talking about the request parameter value, instead I am talking about the generic type implementation. E.g your `class Foo<T> {}` is a class declaration, but `void addStrFoo(Foo<String> strFoo)` materialize the symbol `T` into a real implementation `String`. The parameter binding code can be found at https://github.com/actframework/actframework/tree/develop/src/main/java/act/inject/param. The way to get type implementation of a field can be found at: https://github.com/osglworks/java-di/blob/master/src/main/java/org/osgl/inject/BeanSpec.java#L505

Comment: @GelinLuo Thank you for your reply! I'll sure take a look at how you've done it. I didn't expected generics could materialize into the proper implementation. I'm glad you pointed it out :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this may not be exactly what you are looking for but if you are stuck perhaps consider extracting out the shared variables into its own class and then pass two parameters to your grid method instead of one. Spring Data has a Pageable class that is similar so perhaps you can look at that for inspiration. Then you can just pass a bean with the criteria and another bean with offset and size.  Ex:

```
public Object grid(MyFilter f, Paged p);

public class MyFilter {
  String name;
  ...
}

public class Paged {
  int offset;
  int size;
  ...
}
```