# Deserializing sub-object with type id in top-level object

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm using Jackson to try and deserialize this data structure:

```
{
  "type": "foo",       // or "bar", "baz", etc
  "name": "number 1",
  "params": {
    // parameters specific to type 'foo'
  }
}
```

I know I could use a custom deserializer, but I'm wondering if this is possible to do using just the `@JsonType*` family of annotations?

Right now I have my classes set up something like this:

```
public class TopLevelObject {
    String type;
    String name;
    AbstractParams params;
}

public class FooParams extends AbstractParams {
    String one;
    String two;
}

public class BarParams extends AbstractParams {
    String three;
    String four;
}

abstract public class AbstractParams {
}
```

I can use `@JsonTypeInfo` on the `type` property if I move the property into the `AbstractParams` class, but I can't seem to get the same result while keeping the `type` property in the `TopLevelObject`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)`. But `As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` can only be used for properties. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20914599/1032167).

So you have to put `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation on the  `AbstractParams` field/setter of the `TopLevelObject` class

```
class TopLevelObject {
    public String type;
    public String name;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include= JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
            property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FooParams.class, name = "foo"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BarParams.class, name = "bar")})
    public AbstractParams params;

}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!