# How to use dynamic deserialization on a property using JsonSubTypes?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I have a class `Food` which needs to be used as a deserialization class.

```java
public class Food {

    private VegetableConfiguration vegetableConfiguration;
    private Color color;

    // ...
    // Getters/Setters
}
```

```java
public interface VegetableConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

```java
public class PotatoConfiguration implements VegetableConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

```java
public class CarrotConfiguration implements VegetableConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

```java
public class PepperConfiguration implements VegetableConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

```java
public enum Color {
    BROWN, ORANGE, RED
}
```

I need to select an implementation `VegetableConfiguration` based on `Color` I get from the response.

I'm trying to use `JsonTypeInfo` form Jackson. According to JavaDoc it can be used on a property.

```java
public class Food {


    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            property = "color")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PotatoConfiguration.class, name = "BROWN"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CarrotConfiguration.class, name = "ORANGE"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PepperConfiguration.class, name = "RED"),
    })
    private VegetableConfiguration vegetableConfiguration;
    private Color color;

    // ...
    // Getters/Setters
}
```

but it fails with the following error

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [Food] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class VegetableConfiguration]: missing type id property 'color' (for POJO property 'vegetableConfiguration'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class VegetableConfiguration]: missing type id property 'color' (for POJO property 'vegetableConfiguration')
```

How to make it select an implementation for `VegetableConfiguration` on deserialization depending on `color`?

Preferably without implementing a custom deserializer.

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use? Try to add `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` configuration to `@JsonTypeInfo`.

Comment: @MichałZiober it worked! Feel free to write an answer. I use 2.9.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#EXTERNAL_PROPERTY). From documentation:

> Inclusion mechanism similar to `PROPERTY`, **except that property is
>   included one-level higher in hierarchy**, i.e. as sibling property at
>   same level as JSON Object to type. Note that this choice can only be
>   used for properties, not for types (classes). Trying to use it for
>   classes will result in inclusion strategy of basic PROPERTY instead.

See also:

- [Jackson JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757431/jackson-jsontypeinfo-as-external-property-doesnt-work-as-expected)