# Json Polymorphism Deserialization wihout Type information

Tags: java, json

I think perhaps I am misunderstanding how some of the Jackson libraries work. **I am trying to deserialize a JSON into an object without including type information on the object I am deserializing into.**

For example, I have the `Correspondence` parent-child relationship for contact information shown below:

```
@JsonRootName("correspondence")
public class Correspondence {
    private Contact contact;
    // getter/setter not shown for brevity
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "concreteType")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Person.class, name = "person")})
public interface Contact {
    // just a wrapper interface
}

@JsonRootName("person")
public class Person implements Contact {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // getter/setter not shown for brevity
}
```

Sending the following JSON allows me to deserialize this object with `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` when I have the inclusion property `PROPERTY`. The JSON would be:

```
{
    "correspondence": {
        "contact": {
            "type": "person",
            "firstName": "Johnny",
            "lastName": "Bravo"
        }
    }
}
```

**The above format works**, but the format I want to send in my JSON in is this:

```
{
    "correspondence": {
        "person": {
            "firstName": "Johnny",
            "lastName": "Bravo"
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, the child class of `Contact`, `Person`, is now the rootname of the inner object. I thought this could be accomplished using the inclusion property `WRAPPER_OBJECT`, but for the life of me I cannot seem to get this to work. I have read multiple resources which are all well documented which is why I think I might be misunderstanding how to use the Jackson library to accomplish my goal.

References:
[Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)
[Polymorphic JSON serialization tutorial](http://techtraits.com/programming/2011/07/27/polymorphic-json-serialization-using-jackson/)

Comment: There is also this SO post (and others) that for the life of me would not post correctly in my question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14038270/2607501

Comment: Have you tried adding @JsonUnwrapped to the contact property?

Comment: NoPE, I've set ObjectMapper with a DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE. If I remove that feature it would break other parts of the application.

Comment: unwrap root and JsonUnwrapped are different things - try putting JsonUnwrapped on Correspondence.contact and see if that works for you

Comment: Adding @JsonUnwrapped allowed me to serialize the object to json with the WRAPPER_OBJECT, but not deserialize the json back to an object.

Comment: Ah i see, it is able to serialize the object, but it adds a ": {" before the "associateDetail" which should instead just be a comma.

Comment: Theres no mention of "associateDetail" in your original question

Comment: sorry, I posted example code in the post. Replace my previous statement of "associateDetail" with "person".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76084/discussion-between-prancer-and-mrwiggles).