# Can I serialize subclasses based on an external key with jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

is it possible to deserialize subclasses with Jackson using a type that external? e.g. the type defining the subclass would come from the copy name somehow (using js/json5 syntax here for brevity. This would require some kind of `Pair` class, but it appears there's support in external modules for `vavr`/`commons-lang3`. I can see that the left side of the pair could be a lowercase enum.  I can't seem to find a simple way to do this mapping via annotations, the only thing I've been able to find is having a `type` property, or having the exact classname (which is a bad abstraction imo)

```
[
 copy: {
   source: "foo",
   destination: "bar"
 },
 search_replace: {
   search: "foo",
   replace: "bar",
   destination: "bar"
 }
]
```

Comment: Eh, now that I know what to look for, this is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825603/json-polymorphism-deserialization-wihout-type-information

Answer (score 1):

I am mostly able to do what you want:
The external tagging (Not sure if this is general terminology, serde uses the term.) based on custom names can be achieved through `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` and `JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT`. The class/identifier mapping is then done with `@JsonSubTypes`.
I say mostly able, because it does for some reason seem to require a wrapper object, i.e. I don't know how to make it work with a list as the outermost object, like in your example. (Maybe it can be done with more `TypeReference`s, but I don't know how.)

Some hopefully enlighting sample code:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class ExampleMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(View.of(Rectangle.of(3, 6), Circle.of(5))));
  }

  public static class View {
    public List<Shape> shapes;

    public static View of(Shape... shapes) {
      View ret = new View();
      ret.shapes = List.of(shapes);
      return ret;
    }
  }

  @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
  @JsonSubTypes({
          @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class, name = "round"),
          @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Rectangle.class, name = "pointy")
  })
  public abstract static class Shape {
  }

  public static class Circle extends Shape {
    public int radius;

    public static Circle of(int i) {
      Circle ret = new Circle();
      ret.radius = i;
      return ret;
    }
  }

  public static class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public int w;
    public int h;

    public static Rectangle of(int i, int i1) {
      Rectangle ret = new Rectangle();
      ret.w = i; ret.h = i1;
      return ret;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{"shapes":[{"pointy":{"w":3,"h":6}},{"round":{"radius":5}}]}
```

Deserialization should work just as well.

(Example classes stolen from https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-type-info-with-wrapper.html)