# How to deserialize a json array containing different types of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

Here is a json snippet which contains an array(icons) which can contain two different types of objects(application and folder)

```
{
  "icons": [
    {
      "application": {
        "displayName": "Facebook",
        "bundleId": "com.facebook.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "folder": {
        "some": "value",
        "num": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I create java POJO's modelling this kind of json and then deserialize the same?

I referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038084/json-nest-class-data-binding). But I can't change the json I'm getting to include a 'type' as advised there and then use inheritance for the POJO's of the two different objects.

Comment: Just create a custom deserializer that switches depending on the `key`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider No custom deserializers are required :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No custom deserializers are required. A smart [`@JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) will do the trick.

See below what the classes and interfaces can be like:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = ApplicationIcon.class, name = "application"),
                @Type(value = FolderIcon.class, name = "folder") })
public interface Icon {

}
```

```java
@JsonRootName("application")
public class ApplicationIcon implements Icon {

    public String displayName;
    public String bundleId;

    // Getters and setters ommited
}
```

```java
@JsonRootName("folder")
public class FolderIcon implements Icon {

    public String some;
    public Integer num;

    // Getters and setters ommited
}
```

```java
public class IconWrapper {

    private List<Icon> icons;

    // Getters and setters ommited
}
```

To deserialize your JSON, do as following:

```java
String json = "{\"icons\":[{\"application\":{\"displayName\":\"Facebook\",\"bundleId\":\"com.facebook.com\"}},{\"folder\":{\"some\":\"value\",\"num\":3}}]}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
IconWrapper iconWrapper = mapper.readValue(json, IconWrapper.class);
```