# How to deserialize JSON array with different types?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON array like this:

```json
[
  "0",
  {
    "number": 1,
    "field": "value"
  },
  {
    "number": 2,
    "field": "value"
  }
]
```

The first element to the array is a string.

Is it possible to deserialize it with FasterXML Jackson?

I know how to do it with different objects.
I need to use `@JsonSubTypes` (Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877862/2564509)

The problem with this array is that the first element is String type.

Comment: I'm not set up to test it, but the "only" issue I see compared to the linked solution, is that String is final and can not be made to extend a custom interface. But 1) do you really need a single, custom interface (e.g. List<Object>) ? 2) What about creating a StringWrapper class that holds a String (maybe with a custom (De)Serializer ? 3) What about cheating by extending something not final and String-like, e.g. a CharSequence implementation (sadly, StringBuilder is final too) ?

Comment: @GPI Yes, the String class is final. Because of that, I cannot have a common interface for String and other classes. 
1) I get an array from an API like in the question. I cannot change it. 2) I haven't tried it. So this is the next to try. 3) For my case, it is not a good approach because other elements (objects) are not String-related (they are more specific, like user data).

Comment: My bad, jumped the gun on closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Caveat:* Your situation is an unfortunate edge case.
As such,
the solution is likely to be not wonderful.

This works,
but is not wonderful:

1. First, deserialize as a `List<Object>`.
   In your case, this will result in a List of three elements;
   String,
   LinkedHashMap,
   and LinkedHashMap
2. Next, process each element in the array and,
   process based on the element type;
   a String will be your String element,
   a LinkedHashMap will be the representation of your number-field class.